# Symfony 3.3 service mocks for functional tests

Tags: symfony, functional-testing

Before Symfony 3.3 it was allowed to set a mocked service onto the container. Now with 3.3 a deprecation warning is thrown because the service is already pre-defined.

What is the new standard way to overwrite an existing or pre-defined service in the container to set a mocked service for a functional test?

E.g. in our case we set a new entity manager with a new mocked connection pointing to a cloned database for testing.

```
$container->set('doctrine.orm.entity_manager', $testEm);
```

> Setting the "doctrine.orm.entity_manager" pre-defined service is deprecated since Symfony 3.3 and won't be supported anymore in Symfony 4.0.

Comment: Why you need to mock entity_manager for testing purpose, when you can just change test environment configuration?

Comment: That is not enough for us. We have various database functional tests which each receive a new cloned database to work on. So mocking the entity manager must be possible for each test class or even test method.

Comment: use fixtures and setUp() and tearDown() etc, there are easier and better ways of going about this, instead of actually 'cloning' into an actual seperate  database

Comment: The EntityManager is just one example, we simply have the need to mock a deeply injected service, for that we need another way.
If no other way exists, we are going to extend the Container and set our mocked services manually.

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem just a few days ago and I wrote a library to trick Symfony's DIC: https://github.com/TiMESPLiNTER/proxy-mock

The idea is to override the service in the config_test.yml with a "proxy" from the original service class which redirects all the calls to a mock which then can be set dynamically in the test case.

```
# config_test.yml
services:
    timesplinter.proxy_mock.factory:
        class: timesplinter\ProxyMock\ProxyMockFactory

    acme.api.client:
        factory: 'timesplinter.proxy_mock.factory:create'
        arguments: ['Acme\AppBunde\Services\ApiClient']
```

This will override the service defined in the original service.(xml|yml) with a proxy of it.

In the test case you can then do something like this:

```
// Your container aware test case (this exmaple is for PHPUnit)
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder(ApiClient::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

$container->set('acme.api.client')->setMock($mock);
```

With this your test will run against the mock you provide using the `setMock()` method.

**The library is very new so some feature may be missing. If you use it and miss something please provide a pull request with the desired feature.**